# How to access props inside react render return

Tags: reactjs

I want to set the logo according to the selected theme. But I'm unable to do so as I'm fairly new to react. I am using class component. Do I need to define props function in the constructor?

This is what I've tried:

```
 <Logo src={(props => props.theme.currentTheme === 'dark') ? logo_dark : logo_light} />
```

The code only seems to select light logo. I have used the same code in styling and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Did you try to log the value of `props.theme.currentTheme` and check if the new value of theme was being passed down to your component or not?

Comment: @Umang As jaybhatt said, check if ```props.theme.currentTheme``` really exists. For examples, do you misspell the props name?

Comment: If it's a class component, shouldn't you be using `this.props.theme.currentTheme` instead?

Answer (score 0):

If its a class Component you should use **this.props** to access any props passed down to the class Component.